# Atualizando tabela Mysql usando sqlSave em R

Tags: mysql, r, odbc

Sou novo no R e estou tentando adicionar novas tabelas no banco de dados ,o problema é que sempre mostra essa mensagem:

```
Error in sqlSave(connection, dado, tablename = "teste", rownames = FALSE,  : 
unable to append to table ‘teste’
```

Aonde:

```
dado = pegarDados(arquivoNome,TAG)
colnames(dado) = pegarNomes(arquivoNome,TAG)
sqlSave(connection, dado, tablename = "teste",rownames = FALSE ,colnames = FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

Alguém sabe o que causa isso e como resolver? Estou usando o pacote `RODBC`.

Comment: Qual pacote você está usando?

Comment: Estou usando a RODBC

Comment: Provavelmente isso está acontecendo porque você já tinha criado a tabela "teste" antes, em algum momento, e agora está tentando escrever nela de novo. Para saber se é isso rode `sqlQuery(connection, "drop table teste")` **antes** do `sqlSave()`.

Comment: Funcionou,obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente isso está acontecendo porque você já tinha criado a tabela "teste" antes, em algum momento, e agora está tentando escrever nela de novo. Para saber se é isso rode `sqlQuery(connection, "drop table teste")` antes do `sqlSave()`. Caso você queira fazer um update da tabela, e não salvar por cima, você pode utilizar a função `sqlUpdate()`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez em um trabalho eu precisei adicionar tabelas em um banco de dados de forma incremental. A solução que utilizei foi essa aqui:

```
    ## Cria uma conexão com o banco de dados
con <- dbConnect(drv, user="usuario_do_banco", password="senha", dbname="nome_do_banco", host="url_do_banco")

## Adiciona linha a linha se tabela regras existir ou cria uma nova caso contrário
if(dbExistsTable(con, "regras")) {
  dbGetQuery(con, "delete from regras")
  for (i in 1:length(regras[,1])) {
    insere <- paste('insert into regras values (',"'",regras[i,1],"'",",","'",regras[i,2],"'",',',"'",regras[i,3],"'",',',"'",regras[i,4],"'",',',"'",regras[i,5],"'",')', sep="") ## Formatação específica do meu insert
    dbSendQuery(con, insere)
  }
} else {
    dbWriteTable(con, "regras", regras, row.names=F)
  }
```

Nesse caso eu estava usando o Postgres por meio do pacote RPostgeSQL, mas o pacote RMySQL tem os mesmos comandos e deve funcionar da mesma forma.

No caso de você querer somente criar uma tabela no banco de dados a partir de um data.frame utilize simplesmente:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "nome_da_tabela_a_ser_criada", data_frame, row.names=F)
```

Eu prefiro o RMySQL ao invés do RODBC.